# Android SensorManager.getOrientation before event triggered

Tags: android

I am working on an app for a tablet where the tablet will be in a stand which rotates about a given point.  That means *very little* movement from the tablet when the app is first opened.  The app will display various things depending on the rotation of the tablet in the stand.  What I cannot seem to find how to do no matter how hard I search is to get the initial orientation in degrees or radians which is comparable to the value of `OrientationEventListener.onOrientationChanged(int orientation)`.  I have an OrientationEventListener configured and my idea was that during the default Activities `onCreate` method, I would manually call the OrientationEventListener with an updated value.

Demo code that doesn't run by itself, but illustrates the point:

```
//No problems at this point in the code, the OrientationManager class
//which extends OrientationEventListener properly receives onOrientationChanged
//notices
OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener;
orientationEventListener = new OrientationManager(
                               this,
                               SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL
                           );
orientationEventListener.enable();

//Here's where the problem is... need to get the current orientation 
//and "initialize" the OrientationEventListener
float[] coords = new float[3];
float[] rotation = new float[16];
SensorManager.getOrientation(rotation, coords);

//Test for correct coords values (logs "0.0, -0.0, -0.0")
Log.d("DEBUG", Float.toString(coords[0]) + ", " 
               + Float.toString(coords[1]) + ", " 
               + Float.toString(coords[2])
     );

//Goal is to be able to call orientationEventListener.onOrientationChanged(??)
//with the value that would be sent if the event was called naturally
```

Now, did I submit a question already asked and answered?  I've looked at so many SO posts and haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: It seems you are a bit confused. `OrientationEventListener` returns the rotation of the screen compared to the default (0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees). That is the automatic rotation of the screen so that the user can use the app even if he holds the device upside down. `SensorManager.getOrientation` is actually about a digital compass, which shows the rotation of the device compared to the magnetic north pole, and the pitch and roll of the (compared to the ground level).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  This is my first time trying to do any of this.  Testing the user code below now.

Comment: What I don't understand is why would you want to manually call the OrientationEventListener in the default Activities onCreate method. There is no need to do so. The Android OS will handle orientation changes on it's own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `getOrientationUsingGetRotationMatrix()` method from `DeviceOrientationService`: [Link](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/webkit/DeviceOrientationService.java) :

```
private void getOrientationUsingGetRotationMatrix() {
    if (mGravityVector == null || mMagneticFieldVector == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the rotation matrix.
    // The rotation matrix that transforms from the body frame to the earth frame.
    float[] deviceRotationMatrix = new float[9];
    if (!SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(
            deviceRotationMatrix, null, mGravityVector, mMagneticFieldVector)) {
        return;
    }

    // Convert rotation matrix to rotation angles.
    // Assuming that the rotations are appied in the order listed at
    // http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values
    // the rotations are applied about the same axes and in the same order as required by the
    // API. The only conversions are sign changes as follows.
    // The angles are in radians
    float[] rotationAngles = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getOrientation(deviceRotationMatrix, rotationAngles);
    double alpha = Math.toDegrees(-rotationAngles[0]);
    while (alpha < 0.0) { alpha += 360.0; } // [0, 360)
    double beta = Math.toDegrees(-rotationAngles[1]);
    while (beta < -180.0) { beta += 360.0; } // [-180, 180)
    double gamma = Math.toDegrees(rotationAngles[2]);
    while (gamma < -90.0) { gamma += 360.0; } // [-90, 90)

    maybeSendChange(alpha, beta, gamma);
}
```

Check if `rotation` indeed holds valid values and that `getRotationMatrix(...)` is returning `true`.

Comment: I checked that source code and it requires the gravity vector and magnetic field vector to be initialized which is only triggered by movement as far as I can see.  I won't be able to guarantee initial movement, though, since the tablet will be in a rather sturdy stand.

Comment: @JeremyMiller : You do need to initialise the magnetic sensor and the gravity sensor, but they will give you values almost immediately after initialisation. You have to handle them asynchronously (in an event listener) but on almost every case, your fist set of values will come within a few milliseconds after you have started the sensors. I still think that using sensors is an overkill for your purpose.

Comment: @JeremyMiller User **foibs** is right. Since your device is on a stand, its `orientation` is fixed and will not change. I believe that orientation-changes can be detected while the device's position has some Y-component. Changes while the device is in X-Z plane (laying flat; no Y-component) cannot be detected. The following statement from android docs on `OrientationEventListener` support this: ` ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN is returned when the device is close to flat and the orientation cannot be determined`. In short, an OrientationEventListener is of little use to you... (contd.).

Comment: @JeremyMiller `I won't be able to guarantee initial movement, though, since the tablet will be in a rather sturdy stand`. This is fine. I delayed-launched an activity (while the device was stationary on the table) that used accelerometer and magnetic field sensors to retrieve device's orientation (like above). It gave me valid values. Could you be more specific about the device's degree of freedom? And which orientations are to be detected and acted upon? Does the stand allow the device to take up Portrait(Rotation_0, Roation_180) and Landscape(Rotation_90, Rotation_270) orientations?

Comment: Thank you.  Knowing that the numbers are updated almost immediately, I think this very well may work.  I will implement the code and post back, however, I am awarding @user2558882 the bounty now as even if it's not 100% what I needed, it'll be the best thing I can get.

If it does work 100%, I'll also accept the answer.

To answer your question, http://www.galaxyenclosures.com/media/catalog/product/cache/18/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/g/a/galaxy_tab_3_swivel_01.jpg is the image of the stand.  It allows you to rotate about one axis going through the center of the tablet.

Comment: @JeremyMiller That stand looks great and it provides quite a bit of 'freedom of movement' (saw the assembly/demo video). So yes, you can use an OrientationEventListener. Thank you for granting the bounty. You can post here in case you need further help / or are stuck on a certain issue. I'll try the best I can.

Comment: I finally had a chance to implement.  While the gravity change didn't happen while laying flat, the acceleration change flew like crazy, allowing me to do what I needed.  TIP to others: Build a class based off of this answer and test the alpha/beta/gamma values returned by onOrientationChange to find your desired range.  Worked like a charm!